# Cant fix css for Outlook email

Tags: css, email, outlook, html-email

I have problem to fix CSS for outlook email. My code works good in other email services. This is first time for me to do something like this, so I am not shure am I doing it well.

In this case I cant fix "max-width: 250pt" and I want to my margins are expressed in percentages.

Here is my code,so can someone assist me, or tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
<table class='maint' style='margin: 0 auto;'>
<tr>
<td>
<table class='layout layout--no-gutter' id='llng' >             

<tr>
<td class='column' id='col1'>
<!--[if !mso]-->
<div class='image' id='img'>
<img  style='display: block; text-align: center; border: 0;max-width: 300px; margin-left:10%px; margin-right:5px' src='http://www.epartner.rs/externe_slike/slike_za_mail/computer-science.jpg' alt='c-science' width='285' height='186' />
</div>

<div class='text' style='Margin-left: 10px;Margin-right: 20px;Margin-top: 20px;'>
<h3 style='Margin-top: 0;margin-left:10%;Margin-bottom: 0;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;color: #353638;'>Online Marketing</h3>
<p style='width:270px; Margin-top: 12px;Margin-bottom: 20px; height: 110px; margin-left: 10%px'><span style='color:#353638'><span style='text-align:justify'>Prednost ovog medija le&#382;i u nala&#382;enju ta&#269;no definisane grupe ljudi koja je zainteresovana za va&#353;e poslovanje, i usluge koju nudite.</span></span><span style='color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039); text-align:justify'></span></p>
</div>
<!--[endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
<div style='text-align: left; border: 0;max-width: 225pt;margin-left:350pt; margin-top:-10pt;'>
<img  style='display: block; text-align: left; border: 0;max-width: 225pt;' src='http://www.epartner.rs/externe_slike/slike_za_mail/computer-science.jpg' alt='c-science' width='285' height='186' />
</div>

<div style='Margin-left: 355pt; margin-top:15pt'>
<h3 style='margin-top:8pt;margin-left:10pt;Margin-bottom: 0; text-align: left;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;color: #353638;'>Online Marketing</h3>
<p style='max-width:250pt; Margin-top: 12px;'><span style='color:#353638'><span style='text-align:justify'>Prednost ovog medija le&#382;i u nala&#382;enju ta&#269;no <br /> definisane grupe ljudi koja je zainteresovana za va&#353;e <br /> poslovanje, i usluge koju nudite.</span></span><span style='color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039); text-align:justify'></span></p>
</div>
<![endif]-->
<div style='Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;Margin-bottom: 24px'>
<div style='text-align:left;'>
<!--[if !mso]-->
<a style='border-radius: 4px; margin-left:10%px;display: inline-block;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;text-decoration: none !important;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color: #fff;background-color: #00a551;font-family: Merriweather, Georgia, serif;font-size: 12px;line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 28px; margin-top:45px;' href='http://epartner.rs/usluge/onlineMarketing/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=UslugeOnlineMarketing&utm_campaign=email' target='_blank' data-width='67'>Detaljnije..</a><!--[endif]-->
<!--[if mso]><div style='margin-left:350pt;'><p style='line-height:0; margin-top:30pt;'>&nbsp;</p><v:roundrect xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' href='http://epartner.rs/usluge/onlineMarketing/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=UslugeOnlineMarketing&utm_campaign=email' style='width:92.25pt' arcsize='10%' fillcolor='#00a551' stroke='f'><v:textbox style='mso-fit-shape-to-text:t' inset='0pt,6.75pt,0pt,6.75pt'><center style='font-size:12px;line-height:16.75pt;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Georgia,serif;font-weight:bold;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;mso-text-raise:3pt'>Detaljnije..</center></v:textbox></v:roundrect></div>
<![endif]-->





</div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

In most Email clients you can only use CSS 1 standard, or some CSS 2 standards. Outlook mostly uses CSS 1 standard. Do not even think about CSS 3. Most of the "fancy" looking emails nowadays are just pictures. Unfortunatelly...